# Determining intersection between GeoJSON feature and given coordinates?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, intersection, d3

I'm overlaying a Leaflet map with features of GeoJSON, fetched with D3 and added as SVG elements to the DOM.

My GeoJSON contains too many features to render at once, so my goal is to add to the map only features, that intersect current cursor location, so I can have a smooth hover effect.

I can get current map coordinates of the cursor from a mousemove event, but I have to determine if current coordinates intersect a feature in GeoJSON and exactly what feature is intersected.

Thinking further, maybe I have to make a small buffer, so it's easier for the user to hit the closest feature.

Is there a fast way in Leaflet or D3 (or even pure JavaScript) to get the intersected feature from GeoJSON feature collection?

Answer (score 5):

You can try Turf library and its intersect method: http://turfjs.org/docs/#intersect

Taken from turf examples:

```
var poly1 = {
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "fill": "#0f0"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [[
      [-122.801742, 45.48565],
      [-122.801742, 45.60491],
      [-122.584762, 45.60491],
      [-122.584762, 45.48565],
      [-122.801742, 45.48565]
    ]]
  }
}
var poly2 = {
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "fill": "#00f"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [[
      [-122.520217, 45.535693],
      [-122.64038, 45.553967],
      [-122.720031, 45.526554],
      [-122.669906, 45.507309],
      [-122.723464, 45.446643],
      [-122.532577, 45.408574],
      [-122.487258, 45.477466],
      [-122.520217, 45.535693]
    ]]
  }
}

var polygons = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [poly1, poly2]
};

var intersection = turf.intersect(poly1, poly2);
```

will result in

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          -122.584762,
          45.545508794628965
        ],
        [
          -122.584762,
          45.48565
        ],
        [
          -122.68902729894835,
          45.48565
        ],
        [
          -122.669906,
          45.507309
        ],
        [
          -122.720031,
          45.526554
        ],
        [
          -122.64038,
          45.553967
        ],
        [
          -122.584762,
          45.545508794628965
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You could indeed use this, but a small example would help.

Comment: There's a detailed example in the link.

Comment: True, and turf.js is great, however link only answers are discouraged in Stack Exchange generally on the grounds that links can break.

Comment: I added the example. But if that link will break will kinda void my answer entirely, isn't it? ;)

Comment: I kind of agree with you, but rules are rules :-)

Answer (score 2):

So you retrieve all geoJSON features at once? Perhaps you can utilize a quad tree (especially since you're using D3):

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4343214

Also, perhaps this is outside the scope of your project, but have you looked at Polymaps and/or vector tiles from Tilestache?

http://polymaps.org/ex/tiles.html

http://tilestache.org/doc/TileStache.Vector.html

Comment: Thanks. I've used vector tiles with TileStache. Currently, I could get best performance with adding a utfgrid layer with feature id's in hitgrid. So when I hit a pixel with a specific feature in a grid, I add a corresponding feature from geojson to a map. But this way adds an overhead of loading utfgrid tiles (plus some server overhead to render this tiles). So I thought I can do this check directly in javascript without loading utfgrid tiles. quadtree looks interesting, but does it mean I have to cycle through it somehow on each mousemove to get a needed feature?

Comment: Well, the way I'd conceptualize it is to attach a function to run after each mousemove - e.g., set up your quadtree, find where your cursor is, apply some sort of bounding box around said cursor, and display only those features that are located within the bounding box. A quadtree should ensure that you aren't testing every feature on every mousemove.If you have a ton of features, maybe you can generate a list of centroids/points to use with the quadtree? That way, you only fetch + render a feature when its centroid is found to be in the bounding box?

Comment: I guess using points (or centroids) is risky, because a cursor can cross a line somewhere between vertexes and the function won't find it.

Comment: Ah, true. Maybe a large buffer around the cursor can mitigate that? Interesting problem, sorry I can't be of much help. Perhaps you can generate bounding boxes around each feature and then use svg mouseover effects (i.e. hover) to register which features to render?

Answer (score 1):

May be you can use [kd-tree](https://github.com/ubilabs/kd-tree-javascript) library. You can specify the no of closest features you want and display them. Here is an [example](http://ubilabs.github.io/kd-tree-javascript/examples/map/).